# Displaying Model Data in View using Spring and Spring Data JPA By ModelAndView method

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, model-view-controller, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to display my model data into a view, I used Model and added atribute with the list of data using findAll() data JPA repository method.Currently My program is working. I added my working code.Here I want discussion about passing my list of object using ModelAndView object. When I am using ModelAndView I am unable to pass to view. The working code is like the following,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dHome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public   ModelAndView driverLoad(Model model)
{
List<Driver> driverDetails = new ArrayList<Driver>(); 
driverDetails = (List<Driver>) driverRepo.findAll();
model.addAttribute("driverDetails",driverDetails);
ModelAndView viewObj = new ModelAndView("driverhome");
return viewObj;
}
```

Here can see that I added the list of object to a model instance of Model. And used addAttribute() Method. And Also creates a view driverhome by ModelAndView Object. This code is successfully working . But I need to add the list of object ,ie "driverDetails" to ModelAndView object and need to integrate the view and model into one. Means to ModelAndView Object. How I can do that? When I used ViewObj.addObject("driverDetails",driverDetails) It not accessing. Can any one help me Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make it easier:

```
@GetMapping("/dHome")
public String driverLoad(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("driverDetails", driverRepo.findAll());
    return "driverhome";
}
```

Spring guide: [Serving Web Content with Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)

My [example](https://github.com/Cepr0/crud-sb-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/cepr0/RootController.java)

Comment: Thank You for response sir. I already got using model.addAttribute() method. The above coding is working one. I need to know How i can use my list of object with ModelAndView instance. I am searching an secondary aproach to explore ModelAndView. If that is difficult one, No pblm. I need to explore sending list of my objects to view using ModelAndView

Comment: @Prince Why do you need this? Could you describe your usage scenario?

Comment: My scenario is currently working Sir. I am now learning spring , spring boot, maven , and spring Data JPA. So I am exploring all possible approaches for sending a list of my objects from postgres DB to view. Thats why I trying to implement attach my list of object using ModelAndView. Because I don't know more about different types of implementations.

Comment: @Prince so you just need to render the driver list on the some html page? If so - just use my answer (and look at my example how to render list on [html](https://github.com/Cepr0/crud-sb-demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/users.html) )...

Comment: Ok Sir, Thank you for your resposnse.

Comment: Nice repo, thank you Cepr0